# Парсинг страницы (jsoup) после полной загрузки (обработки JS)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Вообщем есть приложение, приложение парсирует страницу с помощью jsoup и выводит данные на экран. Хочу реализовать мультиязычность, на сайте который парсурую есть модуль перевода от Google, как я понял он записывает в Coocie данные языков для перевода и при загрузке страницы при помощи JavaScript переводит страницу. И в итоге получаем страницу на необходимом нам языке. Столкнулся с проблемой что jsoup может загрузить только исходный код страницы, без обработки ее JS, то есть получаем мы исходную русскую страницу. Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: С помощью jsoup - никак. Попробуйте Selenium. И правильно писать Coo**k**ie.

Comment: @Dmitry, не подскажите где можно посмотреть подробный пример использования Selentium?

Comment: [java Selenium примеры](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=java+selenium+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)